# Spring session bean instantation

Tags: java, spring, jsf, session, dependency-injection

I'm trying to instantize a new session bean with dependency injection. This is what im trying to do

```
<bean id="pluginManager" class="desktop.pluginsystem.PluginManager" scope="singleton">
    <property name="abd" ref="autoBeanDeclarer" />
</bean>
<bean id="userBean" class="webapp.beans.UserBean" scope="session">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="pluginManager"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I tried to pass reference to plugin manager through a property, but it was Null every time! Plugin Manager injection for any other bean declared works fine but in this session scoped bean it doesn't work. When using property it says it's NULL anyways but in using  it says

```
Error creating bean with name 'userBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

And this is UserBean class:

```
public class UserBean {

private PluginManager pm;


public UserBean(PluginManager pm){
    this.pm = pm;

}

public void setPm(PluginManager pm) {
    this.pm = pm;
}
```

}

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your `UserBean` really like that or did you clean it before posting?

Comment: It is exactly like that! I'm just trying it before i continue adding stuff